# Obtener IP de cliente desde javascript o jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como puedo obtener la `IP` real del cliente tanto por `Javascript` si fuera posible.

Esto quiere decir que haya conexión directa, o por medio de un `proxy`, o `router` o lo que fuere, siempre me identifique la `IP` real del computador cliente.

Implemente este código en javascript. Pero solo funciona en algunos casos, y es que no tenga proxy, por lo que en lo personal no me sirve, por que apunta al proxy y no a la `IP` de mi maquina.

**Codigo:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>IP real</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     Mi IP es: <strong id="ipId"></strong>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function get_ip(obj){
            document.getElementById('ipId').innerHTML = obj.ip;
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org/?format=jsonp&callback=get_ip"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: José, te digo lo siguiente con el debido respeto: no agregues "agradezco su interés, gracias, etc" = no son necesarias en las preguntas y respuestas. En cuanto a tu pregunta; hay [varias](http://stackoverflow.com/q/391979/4092887) [respuestas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22318219/4092887) en la red, ¿ya habías consultado alguna de estas opciones?

Comment: Suponiendo que *haya conexión directa* entre uno y otro, ¿ no ? porque si hay mas cosas intermedias (*routers*, *proxys*) ... la cosa cambia bastante.

Comment: ¿Podrías enfocar tu pregunta en un solo lenguaje? La idea es hacer una sola pregunta por publicación

Comment: He votado para que la pregunta se deje abierta. Es una **pregunta  interesante y útil**. Yo mismo hace un tiempo me pasé investigando sobre esto porque necesitaba registrar los usos de una aplicación Android. Estoy compartiendo el código aquí porque es algo que puede ser de utilidad. **Este tipo de preguntas no deben ser cerradas**.

Answer (score 6):

Mediante `JS`, una opción sería usar la `API` de un Servicio web , por ejemplo [Freegeoip](https://freegeoip.net) , la cuál acepta tres formatos de respuesta `JSON` `XML` `CSV` ,  la `URL` se especifica de la siguiente forma.

```
freegeoip.net/{format}/{IP_or_hostname}
```

```js
$.getJSON('//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> Existen más alternativas , algunas se encuentran especificadas en
>   [esta Respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35123097)

Comment: Agradezco la respuesta, sin embargo la verdad que no me funcionó. Me dice una ip no real de este computador por que estoy a través de un proxy, y ademas me indica que estoy en argentina, y estoy en santiago de chile

Comment: José Miguel a mi me funcionó correctamente,  si no para usted,  puede buscar otras opciones en el enlace de SO.

Comment: Entiendo que te haya funcionado, pero por ello indique que necesitaba que pudiera pasar el proxy y no quedarse con esa ip, sino con la del computador en si. De todas formas agradezco tu respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Mira en esta pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript-only. Una de las respuestas recomienda usar WebRTC. Chrome en iOS, Internet Explorer y Safari no han implementado WebRTC todavía.

WebRTC tiene un fallo que hace que uno pueda obtener el IP de un usuario aunque esté usando un VPN (virtual private network). O sea, que este fallo puede ser corregido algún día y una vez corregido este método ya no funcionará. También es posible desactivar el WebRTC en Firefox o sea que no podrás obtener el IP de esos usuarios. Aquí puedes probar tu navegador  https://privacytoolsio.github.io/privacytools.io/webrtc.html

El código simplificado en esa respuesta que solo te da un IP es:

```
var findIP = new Promise(r=>{var w=window,a=new (w.RTCPeerConnection||w.mozRTCPeerConnection||w.webkitRTCPeerConnection)({iceServers:[]}),b=()=>{};a.createDataChannel("");a.createOffer(c=>a.setLocalDescription(c,b,b),b);a.onicecandidate=c=>{try{c.candidate.candidate.match(/([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g).forEach(r)}catch(e){}}})

/*Ejemplo de uso*/
findIP.then(ip => document.write('Tu IP: ', ip)).catch(e => console.error(e))
```

El código que te puede dar varios IP del usuario dependiendo de su red es:

```
function findIP(onNewIP) { //  onNewIp - your listener function for new IPs
  var myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection; //compatibility for firefox and chrome
  var pc = new myPeerConnection({iceServers: []}),
    noop = function() {},
    localIPs = {},
    ipRegex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g,
    key;

  function ipIterate(ip) {
    if (!localIPs[ip]) onNewIP(ip);
    localIPs[ip] = true;
  }
  pc.createDataChannel(""); //create a bogus data channel
  pc.createOffer(function(sdp) {
    sdp.sdp.split('\n').forEach(function(line) {
      if (line.indexOf('candidate') < 0) return;
      line.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
    });
    pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
  }, noop); // create offer and set local description
  pc.onicecandidate = function(ice) { //listen for candidate events
    if (!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex)) return;
    ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex).forEach(ipIterate);
  };
}



var ul = document.createElement('ul');
ul.textContent = 'Your IPs are: '
document.body.appendChild(ul);

function addIP(ip) {
  console.log('got ip: ', ip);
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = ip;
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

findIP(addIP);
```

El código original es de https://github.com/diafygi/webrtc-ips

Answer (score 1):

Lo que esto hace Chrome y Mozilla han equipado la API WebRTC elaborada por la World Wide Web   que aprueba ejecutar solicitudes a servidores STUN este protocolo permite a clientes NAT o de usuarios conseguir las direcciones IP públicas y locales. Estos resultados de solicitud están disponibles para JavaScript, con esto ahora se logra conseguir las direcciones IP públicas y locales de los usuarios en JavaScript. Esta demo es un ejemplo de implementación de eso. Espero te sirva

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
   
    <h4>Tu dirección de IP lOCAL:</h4>
    <ul></ul>
    <h4>Tu dirección de IP Publica:</h4>
    <ul></ul>
    <h4>Tu dirección IPv6:</h4>
    <ul></ul>
    <iframe id="iframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin" style="display: none"></iframe>
    <script>
        //get the IP addresses associated with an account
        function getIPs(callback){
            var ip_dups = {};

            //compatibility for firefox and chrome
            var RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection
                || window.mozRTCPeerConnection
                || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
            var useWebKit = !!window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;

            //bypass naive webrtc blocking using an iframe
            if(!RTCPeerConnection){
                //NOTE: you need to have an iframe in the page right above the script tag
                //
                //<iframe id="iframe" sandbox="allow-same-origin" style="display: none"></iframe>
                //<script>...getIPs called in here...
                //
                var win = iframe.contentWindow;
                RTCPeerConnection = win.RTCPeerConnection
                    || win.mozRTCPeerConnection
                    || win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
                useWebKit = !!win.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
            }

            //minimal requirements for data connection
            var mediaConstraints = {
                optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]
            };

            var servers = {iceServers: [{urls: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"}]};

            //construct a new RTCPeerConnection
            var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(servers, mediaConstraints);

            function handleCandidate(candidate){
                //match just the IP address
                var ip_regex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/
                var ip_addr = ip_regex.exec(candidate)[1];

                //remove duplicates
                if(ip_dups[ip_addr] === undefined)
                    callback(ip_addr);

                ip_dups[ip_addr] = true;
            }

            //listen for candidate events
            pc.onicecandidate = function(ice){

                //skip non-candidate events
                if(ice.candidate)
                    handleCandidate(ice.candidate.candidate);
            };

            //create a bogus data channel
            pc.createDataChannel("");

            //create an offer sdp
            pc.createOffer(function(result){

                //trigger the stun server request
                pc.setLocalDescription(result, function(){}, function(){});

            }, function(){});

            //wait for a while to let everything done
            setTimeout(function(){
                //read candidate info from local description
                var lines = pc.localDescription.sdp.split('\n');

                lines.forEach(function(line){
                    if(line.indexOf('a=candidate:') === 0)
                        handleCandidate(line);
                });
            }, 1000);
        }

        //insert IP addresses into the page
        getIPs(function(ip){
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.textContent = ip;

            //local IPs
            if (ip.match(/^(192\.168\.|169\.254\.|10\.|172\.(1[6-9]|2\d|3[01]))/))
                document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].appendChild(li);

            //IPv6 addresses
            else if (ip.match(/^[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7}$/))
                document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[2].appendChild(li);

            //assume the rest are public IPs
            else
                document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[1].appendChild(li);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No es solo el código sino explicarlo

Comment: Añádelo ahorita y no después, dale editar y agrégalo o podrían votarte negativo

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la mejor respuesta que he encontrado en stackoverflow (Inglés) tanto en Javascript como jQuery en entorno seguro https usando una API gratuita externa:

Obtener IP de cliente en JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
  function getIP(json) {
    document.write("My public IP address is: ", json.ip);
  }
</script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
```

Obtener IP de cliente en jQUERY:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.ipify.org?format=json', function(data){
    console.log(data.ip);
});
```

No he probado Javascript pero en Jquery va perfecto.
Prueba si te coje bien tu IP tan solo escribiendo esto en un tu navegador:
https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP

FUENTE: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/257/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-with-javascript-only

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('#IP_Address').append("Your IP: " + data.query);
    $('#Country').append("Your Country: " + data.country);
    $('#City').append("Your City: " + data.city);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="IP_Address"></div>
<div id="Country"></div>
<div id="City"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lee [answer]: pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente cómo funciona este código. Además, no olvides que estamos en [es.so].

Answer (score -1):

puedes hacerlo con la variable `$_SERVER[]`, en este caso `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`, ejemplo

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Current IP Check</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  Current IP Address: <?php  echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No lo he probado, pero da la IP del servidor o del cliente?, sospecho que da la IP del servidor por el 'REMOTE_ADDR'

Comment: Estimado @JorgeLuisAlcantara el código que publique se ejecuta en el servidor (y no en explorador web) por lo que `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` hace referencia a la dirección remota pero del cliente.

Answer (score -3):

Imprime la variable de PHP

```
echo '<pre>';print_r($SERVER);exit;
```

y ahí puedes seleccionar el IP `SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']`

Comment: Por qué? Siempre recuerda argumentar la respuesta

Comment: eso no es ni javascript ni JQuery como quería el usuario