# Como Obtener la ip privada con jQuery o javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

E estado buscando la manera de obtener la ip privada usando javaScript o jQuery pero no e encontrado algún ejemplo, todos los ejemplos que vi usan algún recurso externo y yo la quiero obtener de manera que no acceda a recursos de terceros

esa es mi pregunta.

si alguien tiene algún ejemplo se los agradecería que me lo proporcionara o que me diga como hacerle gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor lee [ask] y de paso realiza el  [tour], por favor consider editar y mostrar lo que llevas, de otro modo tu pregunta es un tanto amplia y pudiera terminar cerrada

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Obtener IP de cliente desde javascript o jquery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67217/obtener-ip-de-cliente-desde-javascript-o-jquery)

Comment: Las respuestas a las que asociaron esta pregunta no las puedo usar ya que usan complementos externos o usan php y lo que quiero es optenerala de manera local